# Looping inside foreach till first matched element is found

Tags: php, file, foreach, directory, glob

First of all apologies for the vague question title. I couldn't come up with a title that made sense.

I'm looping through image files in a directory using:

```
$folder = 'frames/*';
foreach(glob($folder) as $file)
{

}
```

#### The Requirement

I want to measure each file's size and if it's size is less then `8kb`, move to the next file and check it's size and do so until you get the file whose size is greater than `8kb`. Right now I'm using

```
$size = filesize($file);
if($size<8192) // less than 8kb file
{
    // this is where I need to keep moving until I find the first file that is greater than 8kb
   // then perform some actions with that file
}
// continue looping again to find another instance of file less than 8kb
```

I had a look at `next()` and `current()` but couldn't come up with a solution that I was looking for.

So for a result like this:

```
File 1=> 12kb
File 2=> 15kb
File 3=> 7kb // <-- Found a less than 8kb file, check next one
File 4=> 7kb // <-- Again a less than 8kb, check next one
File 5=> 7kb // <-- Damn! a less than 8kb again..move to next
File 6=> 13kb // <-- Aha! capture this file
File 7=> 12kb
File 8=> 14kb
File 9=> 7kb
File 10=> 7kb
File 11=> 17kb // <-- capture this file again
.
.
and so on
```

#### UPDATE

The complete code that I'm using

```
$folder = 'frames/*';
$prev = false;
foreach(glob($folder) as $file)
{
    $size = filesize($file);    
    if($size<=8192)
    {
       $prev = true;
    }

    if($size=>8192 && $prev == true)
    {
       $prev = false;
       echo $file.'<br />'; // wrong files being printed out    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is keep a variable indicating if the previous analyzed file was a small one or a big one and react accordingly.

Something like this :

```
$folder = 'frames/*';
$prevSmall = false; // use this to check if previous file was small
foreach(glob($folder) as $file)
{
    $size = filesize($file);
    if ($size <= 8192) {
        $prevSmall = true; // remember that this one was small
    }

    // if file is big enough AND previous was a small one we do something
    if($size>8192 && true == $prevSmall)
    {
        $prevSmall = false; // we handle a big one, we reset the variable
        // Do something with this file
    }
}
```

Comment: This will run for all files greater than 8kb. What I want is to find a file less than 8kb first and then capture only the first file which is greater than 8kb and not all

Comment: Thanks. Let me go through it and I'll let you know.

Comment: The logic seems to be correct, but I'm not getting the corrupt output. Let me see if I'm doing anything wrong in my file.

Comment: @asprin if it still does not work try to update your question with your new code so I can take a look at it

Comment: @asprin you are not using the same size to define a small and a big file, is it normal ?

Comment: Could it because scanning is not done in order? Is there way to order `glob` to scan in ascending order?

Comment: Which ascending order? by size? If you want ascending order by size then your problem makes no sense to me

Comment: Ascending order by filename. Currently, the files are named as "Frame_1", "Frame_2", and so on

Comment: And what order does glob() returns? Just print the filename and the filesize in the loop to understand what happens.

Comment: It is actually sorting in alphabetical order here, frame_1000 is before frame_2 when you analyze the string name. You need to sort it yourself in an array first if you want another order i think

Comment: Well, I'm changing the file names to contain only numbers, 1.jpg, 2.jpg...and so on. I think that will solve the problem. +1 for the effort. And it works, I'll accept the answer as well